# Make an item selected by default in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have an application that adds "layers" to a JTable when the user presses a button. The application adds the first layer when a new file is created. I would like this layer to be selected automatically in the JTable. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the selection through the JTable's selection model.

```
 myJTable.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval( index, index );
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple situation:

```
//if needed set selection model
table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
//at first, select row
table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(from, to);
//then select column if needed
table.setColumnSelectionInterval(from, to)
//at the end request focus
table.requestFocusInWindow();
```

Quite more dificult, you have table which allow multiple lines selection:

```
table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
//select needed lines
ListSelectionModel model = table.getSelectionModel();
model.clearSelection();
int[] focusedLines = new int[] {0, 4, 10};
for(int actualRow : focusedLines)
{
    model.addSelectionInterval(actualRow, actualRow);
}
//then select column if needed
table.setColumnSelectionInterval(from, to)
//at the end request focus
table.requestFocusInWindow();
```